# Bounded continuous local martingale of finite variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, bounded-variation, local-martingales

We denote $$M_{\mathrm{loc}} ^{0}:=\{\text{set of cont. local mart. starting in 0}\}$$
$$A:=\{\text{set of cont. processes of fin. variation}\}$$

To prove that their intersection is $\{0\}$ we first prove that any bounded process in their intersection is zero, and than choosing a suitable sequence of stopping times extend to any process.

Now let $X\in M_{\mathrm{loc}}^0 \cap A$ and bounded. Fix $\epsilon \gt 0$ and set $$T_0=0, T_{n+1}:=\inf\left\{t\gt T_n: \left|X_t-X_{T_n}\right|\gt\epsilon\right\}$$ Since $X\in A$ than the stopping times go to $\infty$  (a.s.). Now if I show that the process $\left(X_{T_n}\right)_{n\ge0}$ is a martingale than I'm able to show the statement by a variation argument, but I'm unable to show that this is actually a martingale. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, what about optional stopping?

Comment: A continuous martingale of finite variation is a constant process. This extends to local martingales by a localizing argument. If I were you I would start with the first step and figure out how to extend it to local martingales. You can look up the proof in Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability book. Chapter 15 if I recall correctly.